# Pairing Interview With SQL?

Tags: interviewing, job-search, pair-programming

I have an interview later this afternoon in a format I've never done before:

> In this session, you'll work with an engineer on using data to improve
> the product. The objective will be to model some data and create a
> visual given a couple input data points. The interviewer will provide
> you with a base query to work off of that has some mistakes/poor
> assumptions, and your task will be to ameliorate the situation.

Anyone have any experience doing something like this, either as the interviewee or interviewer?

What can I expect? How should I handle it? Any advice?

Comment: Yes, as an interviewee, but what are your questions?

Comment: What can I expect? How should I handle it? Any advice?

Comment: Particularly queries--like using indexes and not doing a full table scan.

Comment: @mkennedy Well it's being done in Snowflake, which I believe doesn't use indexes, but thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These types of interviews can vary but here is one of my experiences with them.

I was asked by an engineer to design a schema based on a car dealership. I was asked what tables would be needed, what relationships the tables would have, and how a general idea of the types of queries to be run. I was then given a certain amount of time to design the schema and implement it in SQL.

For last minute preparations, I would brush up on the SQL commands for creating a table, specifying keys, and creating constraints.

I would also spend some time looking at some database design documents and study things like one to one, one to many, and many to many. Practice creating a database with all of that stuff and you should be plenty prepared